# Configuring Data Source in WebSphere 6.1 for Oracle 11g XML-DB support

Tags: oracle, websphere, datasource, oracle-xml-db-repository

I am using Oracle's XML database feature and the column is defined as `SYS.XMLTYPE`. I am using the below JDBC code to select/update this field.

```
XMLType xmlType = (XMLType) rs.getObject(1);
stmt.setObject(1, XMLType.createXML(connection, xmlString));
```

I had to configure the data source in Tomcat's context.xml as below to get it to work (by adding the following type, factory and driverClassName).

```
    <Resource
               type="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource"
               factory="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSourceFactory"
               driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
               ...
```

However, when deploying in WebSphere I am getting the below Exceptions. Could anybody help me with the equivalent data source configuration in WAS 6.1 to get rid of these errors?

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: oracle.sql.OPAQUE incompatible with oracle.xdb.XMLType
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcConnection incompatible with oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this and see if that provides you with the required answers

http://community.jboss.org/wiki/MappingXMLToOracleXMLTYPEInIBMWebspsherePlatform

HTH

Manglu

Comment: Most discussions I cam across on this topic seems to suggest WSCallHelper is the only way out, but that's something I truly wanted to avoid. But thanks for the link anyway. I am considering using my own connection pool as an alternative now.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you don't want to dive down the WSCallHelper swamp, but unfortunately I have to concur with prevailing suggestion. I had a similar situation a while back with Oracle and CLOB/BLOB (before they implemented that according to the JDBC standards in the driver) and WSCallHelper was really the only way forward when you have to access the raw JDBC driver in a container managed resource/pool.

Comment: Wanted to avoid any WebSphere specific code because my app is deployed on both Tomcat and WAS in different environments. I am no longer using container managed data source.